# Overlap two PDF in tcppdf

Tags: php, pdf, overlap, tcpdf

I want to overlay two PDF file in same page. I want to use one PDF as background and overlay other PDF data on this. I do not want to concat the two PDFs.

Comment: this is a perfectly valid question I don't know why you got a -1

Comment: had solved this using this example http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/

Comment: add it as an answer so people dont have to scan the comments.

Answer (score 0):

tcppdf definately doesn't support this idea, I'm not even sure if it supports background images? What you could do is covert the pdfs into images, do some image manipulation to make one the background of the other, then convert back to pdf?

I know this sounds messy but the less work done with the pdf generation the better in my experience.